# PrintWriter in Java Socket program

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that has 2 way communication using Sockets.  Client Program presents user with some options, when user selects that option it gets processed by Server Program and returns results back to Client Program.  I am having some trouble with Server Program because it won't process the PrintWriter statement if I put it inside my conditional statement as you can see bellow.

Client:

```
Socket socket = null;

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Connecting to Server");

        socket = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 7003);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        InputStreamReader userInput = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader userBuffer = new BufferedReader(userInput);

        InputStreamReader serverInput = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader serverBuffer = new BufferedReader(serverInput);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        System.out.println("Option 1");
        System.out.println("Option 2");
        System.out.println("Option 3");
        String userOption = userBuffer.readLine();

        os.writeBytes(userOption);

        if (userOption.equals("1"))
        {
            String line = serverBuffer.readLine();              
            System.out.println(line);               
        }

        System.out.println("Closing Client Connection");
        serverBuffer.close();
        serverInput.close();
        print.close();
        socket.close();
        os.close();
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSock = null;
    Socket standSock = null;

    try
    {
        serverSock = new ServerSocket(7003);
        standSock = serverSock.accept();

        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(standSock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(input);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(standSock.getOutputStream(), false);

        String dateTime = (Calendar.getInstance()).getTime().toString();

    if (read.readLine().equals("1"))
    {
        System.out.println("Option 1");
        print.println("You're connected to the Server at: " + dateTime);
    }

        System.out.println("Closing Server Connection");
        read.close();
        input.close();
        print.close();
        standSock.close();

    }
```

I've tested for user input from Client program and its getting it correctly, but the problem is if I move

```
print.println("You're connected to the Server at: " + dateTime);
```

inside the condition statement the program just hangs and eventually times out, but if I move that statement outside the condition statement it works.  Why can't it work if I put it inside my condition statement?

Answer (score 2):

The `os.writeBytes(userOption);` in Client never actually writes a return. You are calling readline() on the server so it waits until you type in a return. The readline() you are calling from System.in actually discards the return you type in so that is never transmitted. 
Adding `+ \n"` to `os.writeBytes(userOption);` should do the trick.

Probably a better option would be to actually use the PrintWriter you are creating in the Client, which will automatically flush the StreamBuffer after calling `print.println(userOption)`. And it requires no extra `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that DataOutputStream only really sends the information after a newline or when you close the stream, however closing the stream will also close the socket.

I would recommend sticking with PrintWriter as it is much easier to manage, especially when in the constructor you can make the second argument true so it "auto-flushes" so whenever you do a println() on that PrintWriter object it will automatically send the information.

Comment: It is PrintWriter that defers the send, not DataOutStream, which is unbuffered.

Comment: I agree that DataOutStream is unbuffered and PrintWriter defers by default but not when you set autoflush to true in the constructor for the PrintWriter object.